# EGit, selecting correct parameters for URI, Host, and Repository Path.

Tags: eclipse, git, url, import, egit

I am very new to GIT and am trying to check out some example projects from the eclipse.org git repositories. I just installed the EGit plugin and have reached a roadblock when trying to enter the correct parameters at the "Import Projects from Git" menu.

The location of the examples I wish to check out are located here.

http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/dsf

However I am unsure how to create the correct URI, Host, and Repository Path from this url.

I would like to be able to explore the different repositories listed on that page (for example the org.eclipse.cdt.examples.dsf folder) and checkout those projects, however I just can't figure out what the correct git url for this would be.

I'm coming from SVN, so I am sure I got some terminology wrong. I have been following this tutorial for using git: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Cloning_Remote_Repositories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on "`Summary`" in the page you mention (http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/dsf), you will get a page (http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/) which displays, **at the bottom** (you need to scroll down), the clone addresses:

> #### Clone

```
git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git
ssh://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git
http://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git
```

You can use one of those addresses to clone from Egit: see "[Cloning Remote Repositories](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Cloning_Remote_Repositories)" from the user manual.

[image: Egit clone]

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Git#Connecting.2C_cloning_a_repo) contains documentation from the Eclipse project about cloning their git repositories.  They show an explicit example for the `org.eclipse.cdt.git` repository.  You can use either this:

```
git clone git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git
```

Or this:

```
git clone http://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git
```

I usually use `git://` URLs when they're available.  They used to be faster, but this may not be true anymore.  Either should work just fine.

In general, it looks like repositories are available from `git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/<PROJECT>/<REPO>`, where it's up to you to correctly substitute `<PROJECT>` and `<REPO>`.